# How to place additional animation of parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery drop down menu with a transition effect as you hover each nav link. My question is, if you can view my demo, you'll notice the text within the div being given the transition effect is popping up very quickly. How would i go about making an additional effect on the child of the div i have now ?

http://jsfiddle.net/MwChT/125/

```
demo
```

Comment: What kind of additional effect do you want?

Comment: i would like to have the menu stay open in this instance...when you open any of the tabs, you can currently hover the div it open, but as soon as you move the mouse to the top on another tab or even the blank area of the menu background, the tab closes and it opens again. I think once your on the top moving around, i'd like the menu to not collapse until you hove off the bottom of the div